# Linking search results to specified pages

Tags: php, hyperlink

For my project I created a search engine to search some books from the database. I also made a bookpage where you can find the whole information of the book and were you can react. But now I'm having trouble with linking the two with each other. In my code you can see the code that I am using to show the information in the search page but the title has to be a LINK to his specified bookpage. How can I fix it? Now I can only see the specified bookpage with f.e. book.php?bid=1 (book id = 1).

```
if ($numrows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $id = $row['book_id'];
        $title = $row['book_title'];
        $author = $row['book_author'];
        $description = $row['book_description'];
        $keywords = $row['book_keywords'];
        $cover = $row['book_cover']; 
        $year = $row['book_year'];
        $feedback_search = "Results found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";
        $feedback_search = "<h1>$cover $title <span>($year)</span></h1><h2><h2><b>Author:</b> $author</h1> <br/> <p>$description</p></h2><hr /> ";
        echo $feedback_search;

    }
} 
else {

    $feedback_search = "<h1>No results found for \"<b>$k</b>\"</h1>";
    echo $feedback_search;

}

// disconnect db
mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [*anchor tag*](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/a/) (`<a>`) to create a link in your html code:

```
$feedback_search = "<h1>$cover <a href='book.php?bid=$id'>$title</a>...
```

Basically, embed the tag and set the `href` attribute to the book info page.  I've also embedded the `$id` value above as well so it knows which book id to display.

Note also that I've used single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes for quotes-within-quotes.  The other solution would be to escape inner quotes with `<a href=\"...`

Comment: The link now is working but I have a new problem. When it goes to the specified page, I get the page without css... The rest is still working...

Comment: I removed the '\' tag and now it is working perfect. Thanks for the help both!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just add an anchor around the title, which links to `book.php` with the book's ID passed to it, e.g:

```
 $feedback_search = "<h1>$cover <a href=\"book.php/?bid=$id\">$title</a> <span>($year)</span></h1><h2><h2><b>Author:</b> $author</h1> <br/> <p>$description</p></h2><hr /> ";
```